# Black Clip Object Detection Using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm trying to detect the black clip present in the below images (highlighted in blue) but unable to get any.
The main purpose is actually to detect whether the clip is present or not (clip can be of black, blue, any other color)

I've also applied binarization but it's still not working.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hps6s.jpg) (highlighted part is the clip which need to be detected)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKLKK.jpg) clip present

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB0mZ.jpg) clip present

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXVKj.jpg) clip not present

[image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owF87.jpg) clip not present

Here is my snippet:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("cropped10.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray[:,:,1],(7,7),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 20, 60)

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Please, give me any suggestion or check if I miss anything, thanks.

Comment: please provide me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @Bilal please help if possible